# How to perfectly center a label within a Google Maps marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

I have several circle markers on a Google map using SVG with google.map.Marker objects. However, I can't seem to be able to center the label perfectly inside the circle. The label could have either 1 or 2 digits.

```
function initMap() {
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3163803, -6.2676661);
  var myOptions = { zoom: 15, center: pos};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

  var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,      
    label: {
      text: "10",
      color: "white"
    },
    icon: {
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + 
        encodeURIComponent('<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="black" fill="rgb(78, 144, 217)" fill-opacity="1.0" stroke-width="1" /></svg>'),
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
    },
    optimized: false,
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

The label '10' looks a bit right-leaning.

[image]

What am I missing here?  Or is this a Google Maps problem?  Working [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/FrankRizzo/pen/GdmjOM).

Comment: Seems perfectly centered to me... especially if you replace `10` with just a `0`. I am counting the exact same number of pixels from one side of the circle to the number on both sides. What browser are you using? If you still believe it's off center, maybe avoid resizing it and create your SVG at the right size in the first place.

Comment: @MrUpsidown  It seems a bit off to me. The screenshot is from Firefox.  On Chrome, it's even worse because the number is a bit higher as well.  https://imgur.com/a/rKW5urs

Comment: It does not for me. https://imgur.com/WioNRXT left is Safari and right is Chrome, on a mac. Try what I suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

The label **is** centred.

Characters are rendered within ‘boxes’ so to speak. It doesn’t matter width of the character the ‘box’ bounds will be the same. What I mean by this is that whilst a ‘1’ is thinner than a ‘0’ to the users perspective, when rendered within the google API they are the same width as they are in ‘boxes’.

A way to test this would be change the label to two of the same characters:

[image]

When changing to a ‘00’ it can be clearly seen that the label is centred even though the right 0 has not moved:

[image: obligatory red lines]

So, to answer your question of what am I missing? The answer is that. The labels are centred – its just each character is rendered at the same width making it seem that it is off centre.

Answer (score 1):

```
labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(24, -12)
```

It's work for me.